# Derivation of Feedforward Gains for current mode control in CCM converter

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, control-system, small-signal

I recently start to read the dissertation of Dr.Ridley, [A New Small-Signal Model for Current-Mode Control](https://www.ridleyengineering.com/education/books/books-current-mode-control.html) and I am stuck on a basic equation.

First we have the function of the inductor current for constant frequency control :
$$ 
R_i<i_L>=v_c-DT_sS_e-\frac{S_fD'T_s}{2}
$$

Which is fine, I get it, then the equation below can be describe :
$$
D=\frac{v_{off}}{v_{on}+v_{off}}\\
D'=\frac{v_{on}}{v_{on}+v_{off}}\\
S_f=\frac{v_{off}R_i}{L}
$$
Normally, if I substitute theses equations in the previous function and perturbing the ON-time voltage, I should get this :
$$ 
\frac{<\hat{i_L}>}{\hat{v_{on}}} = \frac{DS_eT_s}{V_{ap}R_i}-\frac{D^2T_s}{2L}
$$
But I can't. I guess I'm missing something but I don't know what. Do you have any idea ?

EDIT :
Here's what I can get :
$$
<i_L>=-\frac{DT_sS_e}{R_i\hat{v_{on}}}-\frac{D(V_{on}+\hat{v_{on}})T_s}{2L\hat{v_{on}}}
$$

\$T_s\$ is the period of the switching frequency, \$D\$ the duty cycle, \$R_i\$ the current sense resistor, \$v_{on}\$ voltage when switch is ON, \$v_{off}\$ voltage when the switch is OFF, \$v_c\$ is the control voltage. As for \$S_f\$ it's the current slope inductor and \$S_e\$ is the slope compensation of the voltage control as seen below :

[image]

Comment: You might choose to fully explain what **all** the formula symbols represent because you certainly can't rely on the linked document for doing that.

Comment: Where are you stuck ? Are you able to get the first equation which has *three* terms down to *two* terms ? The last terms of both the equations seems to be direct substitution. Please explain in detail where you are stuck.

Comment: Ok I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to obtain a small-signal equation from a large-signal one. The expression \$R_i<i_L>=v_c-DT_sS_e-\frac{S_fD'T_s}{2}\$ is a large-signal one and describes the current leaving terminal *c* in the PWM switch model scaled by the sense resistance \$R_i\$. You can either perturb each of the variables and then sort out dc and ac equations, the latter being the one you want. The other option - which I always use - is partial differentiation.

The equation in question is a function of the duty ratio \$D\$. If you replace \$D\$ by the expressions you gave, you obtain: \$I_L=\frac{v_c}{R_i}-\frac{v_{off}}{v_{on}+v_{off}}T_s\frac{S_e}{R_i}-\frac{\frac{v_{off}R_i}{L}(1-\frac{v_{off}}{v_{off}+v_{off}})}{2R_i}T_s\$. So this function depends on \$v_c\$, \$v_{on}\$ and \$v_{off}\$. If you consider \$v_c\$ and \$v_{off}\$ ac-silent (their derivative is 0), then you can differentiate \$I_L\$ with respect to \$v_{on}\$ and obtain:

[image]

Factor the on- and off-voltages to reveal the duty ratio \$D\$ again. You see that a term remains and this is \$(v_{on}+v_{off})\$. If you look back at the PWM switch model, you realize that the dc on-time voltage is labeled \$V_{ac}\$ while the off-time voltage is labeled \$V_{cp}\$. Therefore, substituting these values in the on and off sum leads to: \$V_{on}+V_{off}=V_{ac}+V_{cp}=V_{ap}\$. It leads to:

[image]

If you carry on the exercise, you obtain the *invariant* gain \$k'_f\$ as follows:

[image]

You can now repeat the exercise for \$k'_r\$. If you want to simulate the entire model, there you go:

[image]

As you can see from the above, Ridley's model cannot find its dc operating point and is therefore constrained to ac simulations only. If you want to explore transient simulations with a current-mode model, I would recommend Vatché Vorpérian's version which predicts sub-harmonic oscillations with only two current sources. It is unbeatable in terms of simplicity. It has been extensively described in the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071823468) I published (with an original auto-toggling CCM-DCM model) but also through many APEC seminars ([2013](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202013.pdf) and [2014](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202014.pdf)) I taught.